# Install extensions mongodb in php 7.4 failed with error symbol not found in flat namespace (_ZSTD_compress)

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp, apple-m1, php-mongodb

When I try to install extension mongodb for php 7.4 I have an error in log and extension not work

This Error is:
[06-Sep-2023 10:38:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mongodb.so (dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mongodb.so, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace (_ZSTD_compress)), /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mongodb.so.so (dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mongodb.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mongodb.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0

Command I used: pecl install mongodb
it don't have any error when install and when I check pecl list it return
Package Version State
mongodb 1.16.2  stable

the file mongodb.so is created. And put exactly in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mongodb.so

But when I start server the extension not work and not show in phpinfo.
I think I miss some dependencies or wrong when run build mongodb extension with pecl. Because I use another mac build it not have this problem.

Do you know what reason for this error ? I try with old version extension and another version but it still have error.
Hope I find a answer.

I using
MAMP
macOS 12.6 M1
PHP 7.4.33 in MAMP

Know what wrong in here

Comment: Most likely the version of `mongodb.so` that you installed is for a different version of PHP. Download and install from this site: https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

Comment: Another possibility is the zstd extension is missing: https://pecl.php.net/package/zstd